# Css namespace in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

How can i add namespaces to css in a rails project.

I have 2 predefined css files, and 2 application layouts, I would like the first to use 1 css and the other the second. My css files have styles for the same classes so things get mixed up if I can't separate them somehow.

One of my controllers uses admin namespace.
I have tried to copy the 1st css into an admin folder, but it doesn't seem to work.

Folder structure:

```
stylesheets\admin\screen.css
           \styles.css

views\layouts\application.html.haml 
             \aplication2.html.haml
```

---UPDDATE---

aplication.html.haml :

```
%html
 %head
 %title Page
 = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" =>  true 
 = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" =>  true 
 = csrf_meta_tags
 = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
 %body
  .wrapper
   .page
     .header-container
       .header
         .quick-access
           %form#search_mini_form{action: "product_list.html", method: "get"}
             .form-search
               %label{for: "search"} Search:
               %input#search.input-text{maxlength: "128", name: "q", type: "text", value: ""}/ 
              %button.button{title: "Search", type: "submit"}
                %span
                  %span Search
          %p.welcome-msg Default welcome msg!
          %ul.links
            %li.first
              %a{href: "dashboard.html", title: "My Account"} My Account
            %li
              %a.top-link-cart{href: "cart.html", title: "My Cart"} My Cart
            %li.last
              %a.top-link-checkout{href: "checkout.html", title: "Checkout"} Checkout
    .nav-container
      %ul#nav
        - @categories.each do  |cat|
          %li.level0.nav-1.level-top.first
            %a.level-top{href: "#"}
              %span=cat.label
        = yield
    .col-left.sidebar
      .col-right.sidebar
        .block.block-cart
          .block-title
            %strong
              %span My Cart
          .block-content
            %p.empty You have no items in your shopping cart.
  .footer-container
    .footer
      %ul
        %li
          %a{href: "#"} About Us
        %li
          %a{href: "#"} Customer Service
        %li.last.privacy
          %a{href: "#"} Privacy Policy
      %ul.links
        %li.first
          %a{href: "#", title: "Site Map"} Site Map
        %li
          %a{href: "#", title: "Search Terms"} Search Terms
        %li
          %a{href: "#", title: "Orders and Returns"} Orders and Returns
        %li.last
          %a{href: "#", title: "Contact Us"} Contact Us
```

if i change `= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" =>  true` to `= stylesheet_link_tag "admin/screen.css", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" =>  true` all the style is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of your application templates put --

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "admin/screen", :media => "all" %>
```

and in the other put --

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "styles", :media => "all" %>
```

If you end up calling the application.css file into both templates you will see that it calls in the whole tree --

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

This makes the layout call in every existing stylesheet.  You just need to be more specific in which stylesheets you call into your application.

============== UPDATE ==============

Since you are using Rails 4 and HAML your replaced lines would look like this --

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "admin/screen", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

and

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "styles", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

corresponding with the proper template, of course.

============ ANOTHER UPDATE ===========

Assuming you have additional stylesheets you would like to include in each of these templates you can include them by separating the names with commas. See the example below --

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "styles", "another-stylesheet", "and-another-one" media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

Comment: so i should replace these lines: = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" =>  true with the ones you wrote?

Comment: yes this is exactly what i have tried, and if i delete the original line all css is lost

Comment: @LogofaT - Are there additional css files you are trying to pull into the templates?  Perhaps making calls to those files as well would fix that problem?

Comment: the first template needs just the one that i specified, the second template needs more css files (widgets.css)

Comment: Yes, actually this is how I have added them. The second one works already the first one (with only 1 css) gives me problems... Anyway thank you for youre struggles.

Comment: @LogofaT - what is the issue with the first template?

Comment: After I have changed that line, the template 1 looses all his style

Comment: @LogofaT - dude, add your layout code into your question so I can give you better guidance....

Comment: @LogofaT - Do you have any styling written in your application.css file? Also, why don't you move the screen.css file out of the admin folder and into the stylesheets folder and name it adminScreen.css (please change the name in the layout as needed). See what that gets ya.

Comment: thanks for your help, you were right all over, the help you offered is correct. Something is messed up in the css files, that's why i had problems. I have accepted and voted your answer.